# How to add element at specific index/position in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have an ordered LinkedHashMap  and i want to add element at specific index , say at first place or last place in the map.
How can i add element in LinkedHashMap at an specific position?

Even if I could add an element to FIRST or LAST position in LinkedHashMap would help!

Comment: From the docs: "Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can not change the order. It is `insert-order` (by default) or `access-order` with this constructor:

> `public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)`
>
> - Constructs an empty LinkedHashMap instance with the specified initial capacity, load factor and ordering mode.
> - Parameters:
>         initialCapacity - the initial capacity
>         loadFactor - the load factor
>         accessOrder - the ordering mode - true for access-order, false for insertion-order
> - Throws:
>         IllegalArgumentException - if the initial capacity is negative or the load factor is nonpositive

See: [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Tks. It means ONLY order which i can add an element is LAST place. As u mentioned it maintain order, so i assumed it will add any new element at the last index! Actually I just needed to add elements at FIRST or LAST place. Last place i can get , for to add at first place may be i can  add this to so other map at the end?

Comment: You could create a new list with the new element and the the complete other list after with addAll(); but that is waste of memory and the map is not created for this purpose.

Comment: Tks.That looks like the only solution with LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @supernova You can always build your own, this is not a limitation of a LinkedHashMap, but a limitation of Java's LinkedHashMap implementation

Comment: This is no longer accurate as of Java 21, as elements can now be added to the start or end of the `LinkedHashMap` using the new `putFirst` and `putLast` methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76888014/1108305

Answer (score 32):

You could do this element adding to 1. or last place:

**Adding to last place ►** You just need to remove the previous entry from the map like this:

```
map.remove(key);
map.put(key,value);
```

**Adding to first place ►** It's a bit more complicated, you need to clone the map, clear it, put the 1. value to it, and put the new map to it, like this:

I'm using maps with String keys and Group (my custom class) values:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Group> newMap=(LinkedHashMap<String, Group>) map.clone();
map.clear();
map.put(key, value);
map.putAll(newMap);
```

As you see, with these methods you can add unlimited amount of things to the begin and to the end of the map.

Comment: Be aware that using this method creates a copy of the objects in the map. Something might break if you are using this objects elsewhere.

Comment: Be aware of the memory overhead created by doing this. Best to avoid using this.

Comment: @Omaraf it creates shallow copy of the map. In the end "map" is the same object and keys and values are the same objects as well. If map have not many keys memory overhead will not be huge. But of cause - if you can - use another data structure for this :)

Answer (score 17):

### Apache Commons solution : `ListOrderedMap`

Since the JDK's `LinkedHashMap` ensures only insertion order retrieval, in case you we want to insert at an index, we can use alternatively Apache Commons' `ListOrderedMap`. It does it as it sounds - by having a list to maintain the order of insertion with the corresponding index and a normal map to insert as we generally do. Here is what the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html#put(int,%20K,%20V)) say:

> ```
> public class ListOrderedMap<K,V>
> extends AbstractMapDecorator<K,V>
> implements OrderedMap<K,V>, Serializable
> ```
>
> Decorates a `Map` to ensure that the order of addition is retained
>   using a List to maintain order.
>
> The order will be used via the iterators and `toArray` methods on the
>   views. The order is also returned by the `MapIterator`. The
>   `orderedMapIterator()` method accesses an iterator that can iterate
>   both forwards and backwards through the map. In addition,
>   non-interface methods are provided to access the map by index.
>
> If an object is added to the Map for a second time, it will remain in
>   the original position in the iteration.
>
> Note that `ListOrderedMap` is not synchronized and is not thread-safe.
>   If you wish to use this map from multiple threads concurrently, you
>   must use appropriate synchronization. The simplest approach is to wrap
>   this map using `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)`. This class may
>   throw exceptions when accessed by concurrent threads without
>   synchronization.
>
> Note that `ListOrderedMap` doesn't work with `IdentityHashMap`,
>   `CaseInsensitiveMap`, or similar maps that violate the general
>   contract of `Map`. The `ListOrderedMap` (or, more precisely, the
>   underlying `List`) is relying on `equals()`. This is fine, as long as
>   the decorated `Map` is also based on `equals()`, and `hashCode()`,
>   which `IdentityHashMap`, and `CaseInsensitiveMap` don't: The former
>   uses `==`, and the latter uses `equals()` on a lower-cased key.

Here is its implementation for adding to a position:

```
        /**
428     * Puts a key-value mapping into the map at the specified index.
429     * <p>
430     * If the map already contains the key, then the original mapping
431     * is removed and the new mapping added at the specified index.
432     * The remove may change the effect of the index. The index is
433     * always calculated relative to the original state of the map.
434     * <p>
435     * Thus the steps are: (1) remove the existing key-value mapping,
436     * then (2) insert the new key-value mapping at the position it
437     * would have been inserted had the remove not occurred.
438     *
439     * @param index  the index at which the mapping should be inserted
440     * @param key  the key
441     * @param value  the value
442     * @return the value previously mapped to the key
443     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range [0, size]
444     * @since 3.2
445     */
446    public V put(int index, final K key, final V value) {
447        if (index < 0 || index > insertOrder.size()) {
448            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size: " + insertOrder.size());
449        }
450
451        final Map<K, V> m = decorated();
452        if (m.containsKey(key)) {
453            final V result = m.remove(key);
454            final int pos = insertOrder.indexOf(key);
455            insertOrder.remove(pos);
456            if (pos < index) {
457                index--;
458            }
459            insertOrder.add(index, key);
460            m.put(key, value);
461            return result;
462        }
463        insertOrder.add(index, key);
464        m.put(key, value);
465        return null;
466    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public static <K, V> void add(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map, int index, K key, V value) {
  assert (map != null);
  assert !map.containsKey(key);
  assert (index >= 0) && (index < map.size());

  int i = 0;
  List<Entry<K, V>> rest = new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>();
  for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (i++ >= index) {
      rest.add(entry);
    }
  }
  map.put(key, value);
  for (int j = 0; j < rest.size(); j++) {
    Entry<K, V> entry = rest.get(j);
    map.remove(entry.getKey());
    map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just divide you `LinkedHashMap` on 2 arrays. Make first array with size `index - 1` and put at the end new `Entry`. Then fill first array with entries from the second one

Answer (score 1):

```
...

LinkedHashMap<String, StringExtension> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map.put("4", new StringExtension("4", "a"));
map.put("1", new StringExtension("1", "b"));
map.put("3", new StringExtension("3", "c"));
map.put("2", new StringExtension("2", "d"));

for (Map.Entry<String, StringExtension> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Log.e("Test", "" + entry.getKey() + " - "+ entry.getValue().value);
}


Collection<StringExtension> temp = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
StringExtension value = map.remove("3");
map.clear();
map.put(value.key, value);

for (StringExtension val : temp) {
    map.put(val.key, val);
}

Log.e("Test", "---");

for (Map.Entry<String, StringExtension> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Log.e("Test", "" + entry.getKey() + " - "+ entry.getValue().value);
}

...

private class StringExtension
{
    String key;
    String value;

    public StringExtension(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit long for such a simple question.

Comment: Agreed. I had the same problem and didn't find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in other answers, it is certainly not recommended as by inserting a value you will go against the system.

**Why?**
Because LinkedHashMap is backed by a HashMap and a LinkedList.
The last is used in order to preserve insertion order.
Obviously, LinkedList is pretty good in insertion to the head and to the tale (doubly-linked).
It provides O(1) time complexity for this operation.
However, it is very slow in insertion to a certain position as in order to find this position you got to iterate all over the list, which in the worst case will take O(n) what is quite expensive especially for large datasets.

I personally do not recommend it as it is quite inefficient,
but if you understand the cons and it is what you want,
you may use this extension function in order to **insert a key-pair onto a certain position**.

```
fun <K, V> LinkedHashMap<K, V>.insertAtIndex(key: K, value: V, index: Int) {
    if (index < 0) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot insert into negative index")
    }
    if (index > size) {
        put(key, value)
        return
    }
    val holderMap = LinkedHashMap<K, V>(size + 1)
    entries.forEachIndexed { i, entry->
        if (i == index) {
            holderMap.put(key, value)
        }
        holderMap.put(entry.key, entry.value)
    }
    clear()
    putAll(holderMap)
}
```

It will take O(n) time and  O(n) space.

Answer (score 1):

An element can be added as the first or last element using the [`putFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#putFirst(K,V)) and [`putLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#putLast(K,V)) methods which were added to `LinkedHashMap` in Java 21.

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> linkedHashMap = // ...

linkedHashMap.put("A", 1);
linkedHashMap.putLast("B", 2);
linkedHashMap.putFirst("C", 3);

// linkedHashMap is now [C=3, A=1, B=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a `Map`, it doesn't have indexes.  It has buckets.  The way it works is when you do a

`put(key, val)`

It hashes the key to find out which bucket to put the val in.

The `LinkedHashMap` maintains a doubly linked list so it can record the order in which entries are inserted (or accessed, depending on how you instantiate the map).  There is no method on the API on the Map to insert a key,val pair at a certain index of the linked list, because that is not the purpose it serves.

Comment: Since `Map` doesn't define order of entries during iteration, a `LinkedHashMap` is an OO-wise correct implementation and refinement of the contract. The question being asked is whether the contract extends to insertion into the linked list somewhere other than tail. So the argument that Map is not supposed to allow control of insertion location doesn't hold.

Comment: @dilum, I completely disagree with your last sentence.  The OP said "I have an ordered LinkedHashMap and i want to add element at specific index".  That makes no sense.  Map's dont have indexes, they have keys, which have completely different semantics.  Also, I didn't argue "...that Map is not supposed to allow control of insertion location".  All I said is it doesn't use an index.  As a matter of fact, you control the insertion location via the key.

Comment: I see your point. When I read index, i didn't take it as a number as much as an location pointer (e.g other key, well known head/tail, or semi-consumed iterator.) At the same time, it is quite possible to have O(1) key-based lookups and O(log n) index based lookup / insertion using hash based composite structure.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Maps are supposed to have no index, however LinkedHashMap supports both insertion-ordered indexes and keys, as what the javadoc describes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the data being applied on the `Map` comes from a `List` (Collection), then you should create a reversed *loop* that starts reading from the end of that list till it gets to the first like this:
`for (int key = collection.size()-1; key > map.size(); key--) { Data data = collection.get(key); map.put(key, data); }`

Answer (score 0):

#### The simplest solution is:

1. Cast `LinkedHashMap` to `List`
2. Add the item to the specific index
3. Cast the `List` to `LinkedHashMap` again

```
public static <K, V> LinkedHashMap<K, V> addToSpecificIndex(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V> value, int index) {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> toList = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        toList.add(index, value);
        
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> toMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : toList)
            toMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        return toMap;
    }
```